# Discussion the possible solutions and the issues of

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA, and I have a question about one of the practice assignments.
The question is:

Given an int n, return true if it is within 10 of 100 or 200.

Why do the codes below have errors (bad operand types for binary operator '<=' or '<')?

```
public boolean nearHundred(int n) {
  return (90 <= n <= 110) || (190 <= n <= 210);
}


public boolean nearHundred(int n) {
  return (89 < n <  111) || (189 < n <  211);
}
```

I finally figured out the solution, but I was wondering if there is a better solution for the "absolute" value.

```
public boolean nearHundred(int n) {
  
  if(n <= 100){
    return (100-n)<=10;
  }      
  if (n>=100 && n <= 200){
    return (n-100) <=10 || (200-n) <=10; 
  }
  if (n > 200){
    return (n-200)<=10;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can't chain logical operations in Java like `90 <= n <= 110`. You need to compare separately and use `&&` and/or `||` (`90 <= n && n <= 110` for that example)

Comment: For clarity's sake, the reason you can't chain those logical operations is that a comparison such as `90 <= n` evaluates to a boolean (`true` or `false`), and a boolean doesn't have a `<=` comparison. `90 <= n <= 110` essentially becomes `true/false <= 110`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

add &&s between your operations so switch `return (90 <= n <= 110) || (190 <= n <= 210);`
to something like

`return (90 <= n && n <= 110) || (190 <= n && n <= 210);`
(you can't change operations like that)

Comment: Ah, got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot chain logical operations like a > b > c. You need to use && to connect two parts.

```
  90 <= n && n <= 110 || 190 <= n && n <= 210
```

"and" is executed before "or", you don't need parenthesis, but you can add them for readability.

```
 (90 <= n && n <= 110) || (190 <= n && n <= 210)
```

In you case you can also get the absolute value after subtraction:

```
 Math.abs(100 - n) <= 10 || Math.abs(200 - n) <= 10
```

Alternately you can use Range class from the Guava library:

```
 Range.closed(90, 110).contains(n) || Range.closed(190, 210).contains(n)
```

Apache Commons Lang has a similar class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Math.abs()

> The java.lang.Math.abs(int a) returns the absolute value of an int value

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_abs_int.htm

Comment: Thank you so much! I will learn more about Math.abs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Range](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) class:

```
Range<Integer> lowerRange = Range.between(90,110);
Range<Integer> upperRange = Range.between(190,210);
return lowerRange.contains(n) || upperRange.contains(n);
```